# Formatting multiple fields at once in RDL or RDLC

Tags: rdlc, reporting-services, rdl

Over the years, I've been working with SSRS reports (RDL and RDLC) but I have not found a solution to this problem:   Let's say I have x number of fields in my report.  I would like to highlight all the fields at once and modify the background-color, foreground-color, font and font size, for all fields at the same time.

Is this possible?  I've searched on the web and I've experimented with the report designer, and I have not found anything that allows me to do this (other than modifying the underlying XML directly, which is not an option).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Select all the controls in the designer and press F4 for properties. Change the background color, font etc.

Comment: What a lifesaver. I was about to go mad with all the clicking I had to do.

Comment: That works for some properties, like alignments and such, but for borders, it does not. I can only specify it if I type the correct format string, like Black,,LightGray, for colors, etc. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to just select all fields and go to properties->format->paste from another fields format. That's it.